# assetForURL always return asset as null

Tags: objective-c, alasset

I have a video file stored in the tmp directory, the url is valid, and the video is valid.
The problem is that i get null value in the resultBlock no matter what url i pass in.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[al assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
   NSLog(@"%@", asset); //asset is null/nil 
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"Failed creating asset from url with error: %@", [error description]);
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your video is in the `tmp` directory then it isn't in the asset store associated with the `ALAssetsLibrary` and you will need to access the video data using standard file loading APIs (like `NSFileManager` / `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:...`.

If you want the video to be managed by the `ALAssetsLibrary`, you need to call `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:` to import the video. The `completionBlock` will then provide you with an asset library URL (`assetURL`) which can be used to retrieve the video later (from `ALAssetsLibrary`).

Comment: Yeah, but then the video will be stored in the cameraRoll as well, and that is unwanted result for me. I guess i need to think how to get around that...

thanks.